Auth0 - How can I generate an access token specifically for Playwright tests?
My project relies on the @auth0/auth0-react package for authentication. In my end-to-end Playwright tests, I need to programmatically obtain the access token to interact with my app's REST APIs. Any advice on how to achieve this would be greatly appreciated. Thank you!

to obtain the access token programmatically using the @auth0/auth0-react package in playwright tests.
Actually, you can create a separate authentication setup to test that auth and save the authentication state to a file.
something like this
import { test as setup, expect } from '@playwright/test';
import {WebAuth } from '@auth0/auth0-react';
const authFile = 'file path'
setup('authenticate', async ({ page }) => {
const auth0 = new Webauth ({ 
domain: 'your domain'
clientID: 'client-id'
redirectURL: 'locahost', // I am using local host for now 
// Rest of your code goes here });}

